# How to write "<%" in a erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an .erb file where I'd like to return the following text:

Name <%r>

When I render this file, the erb interprets the <% as a ruby code and doesn't render the % signal.

I found one way to do this, putting the % signal in a String like this:

```
Name <<%= "%" %>r>
```

But this is very ugly. Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are looking for double percents

```
<%%r%>
```

This is used extensively when using erb templates to generate erb templates.

**update**

```
<%%r>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use `&lt;` to replace `<` if it is just plain html

Comment: In StackOverflow, you can surround stuff with <code> to escape and keep from having to put a space.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write `<` directly into markup, use `&lt;`, `&gt;`, etc.